# watir equivalent to "evaluateOnNewDocument"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir

How can we execute custom javascript before execution of javascript on page where we `.goto`  like `evaluateOnNewDocument` in Puppeteer ?

Another way can be : inject  (or file) to execute it before native script of page, but I don't know how to do this with Watir (& Ruby on Rails 5) ?

Comment: I don't think you'll have a lot of luck doing this with Watir or Selenium as they aren't built for this. They allow injecting scripts afterwards, but they don't provide much control over the initial loading. The best I can think of is to create a proxy that manipulates the response before it gets back to the browser.

Comment: @JustinKo Good idea but you know a method to make a proxy like this? I have no idea how can that be functioned ... :s

Comment: You could try the Ruby gem Webrick. I've heard to people using it before, but unfortunately, cannot say I've done it myself.